# How can I get an accurate height value from the gradient noise in shader graph based on an object's world x and z position values in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-physics, game-development

So the solution I currently have actually works for a couple of seconds, then it goes out of sync.
Here is how the shader graph looks:

[image]

Here is how the code looks (the code is attached to the object). I assign a global time float to the shader each frame to ensure that the time on shader and in the code doesn't go out of sync.

[image]

Here is how the gradient noise code looks like. I don't really understand this part (I got it from google), but it SHOULD be at least a bit accurate since the object does sync up with the noise for a couple of seconds before slowly going out of sync.

[image]

Here is how it looks in game. You can see how towards the end it starts to get out of sync:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFOUd.jpg

Does anyone see how I could manage to fix this? Or if anyone has a better way to go about doing this, I'd really appreciate it :)

I haven't really tried anything else to be honest, I've looked all around google and I didn't find a solution for this, only people asking questions about the same problem and not getting responses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.